# What type of screens do I need for this crank case window?

Tags: windows, screens

Can someone please advise me on the type of screens and where to buy for this type of crank case window?

[image: bottom]

[image: left bottom corner]

[image: right bottom corner]

[image: full window]

Here were some options from screenitagain.com (Lowes)
Which of these screen frame profiles do I need?

[image: which of these screen frame profiles?]

Which of these fasteners do I need?  Knife latch looks promising
[image]

Comment: The needed "screen frame profile/width" would be determined by the width of the window channel, you need to measure it. The knife latch is for specific windows designed for it, use a flush mount keeper (not pictured in list above) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided against drilling into the window frames and will use screens and 3M double stick tape.  The screens sit indoor and 3M double stick tape are strong and reliable enough to hold a window screen in place.  Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 3):

The screen will sit where the blue lines are, up against that small lip (sorry bout the poor drawing skills). It will be held in by flush mount clips like shown below. You will need to drill small pilot holes for the clip screws.

You can have the screens built to your custom size at a good hardware store or home center. **Do not** get the cheap screens with the lame plastic corner pieces, get good heavy gauge mitered aluminum frames.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!  I wasn't able to see the flush clip option on screenitagain.com.  Options were: a) plunger bolt b) wire loop c) knife latch d) lift tab e) friction hinge f) tension spring g) slide in leaf spring h) bale clips  I see: Also, do you know which frame profile I should use?

Comment: I think the screen channel is behind where you have the blue lines. It would use the spring type clips (next to last on second row) on the top edge of the screen and handle (like the second fastener pic), as far as how wide the OP needs to measure that channel's depth.  I can't make artwork right now or I'd make a new answer.

Comment: OP needs to look at that channel, I don't see any frame extrusion separating that channel from the window itself, leading me to believe that is where the weatherstrip is.

Comment: Correct, the area behind the blue line (channel) is where the weather strip is.  Im hesitant about the flush mount clips because I don't want to drill holes into the window frame.  Any other ideas?

Comment: If you are careful with your measurements you could use *spring clips*, one on each side at the top (middle image bottom row of "fastener" pics above), and a plastic pull tab on the bottom (4th image from left top row of "fastener" pics above). The spring clips will hold the frame in under spring tension alone, the pull tab helps you insert and remove the screen. IMO this is not the best (most secure) way but it is an option. Do not worry too much about drilling the frame for screw holes, it is a very common attachment method for casement window screens.

Comment: Forget about the knife latch, they are difficult to properly install and few screen shops still have the jig and punch tools needed. Kind of a lost art.